# How to do a WHERE CASE WHEN in doctrine's queryBuilder

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, dql

i have the following function using query builder:

```php
    public function showForJustWhoCanSee() {
        $nextToSign = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
        $nextToSign->select('u')
            ->from('HospitalApi\Entity\EletronicDocumentSignature', 's')
            ->innerJoin('HospitalApi\Entity\User', 'u', 'WITH', 's.user = u')
            ->where('s._document = :documentId')
            ->setParameter('documentId', 'ed.id')
            ->andWhere('s.signed = 0')
            ->setMaxResults('1')
            ->orderBy('s.order', 'ASC');


        $subquery = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
        $subquery->select('userSignature')
            ->from('HospitalApi\Entity\EletronicDocumentSignature', 'signature')
            ->innerJoin('HospitalApi\Entity\User', 'userSignature', 'WITH', 'userSignature = signature.user')
            //->where('signature.signed = 0')
            ->groupBy('signature._document')
            ->orderBy('signature.order', 'ASC');

        $select = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
        $select->select('ed')
            ->from($this->getEntityPath(), 'ed')
            ->innerJoin("HospitalApi\Entity\User", "u", "with", "ed.user = u")
            ->leftJoin("HospitalApi\Entity\EletronicDocumentSignature", 'eds', 'WITH', 'eds._document = ed')
            ->leftJoin("eds.user", 'us', 'WITH', 'u = :user OR us = :user')
            ->where( $select->expr()->eq( 'us', $select->expr()->any( $subquery->getDQL() )) )
            //   ->Need a andWhere here<-
            ->orwhere('u = :user')
            ->setParameter( 'user', $this->getSession() )
            ->andWhere('ed.c_removed = 0');
        return $select;
    }
```

I would like to know how i can add a andWhere() clause to the $select query that does the following:

```sql
CASE WHEN 'ed.user' = ':user' THEN $nextToSign = ':user'
```

I have tried

```
->andWhere( 'CASE WHEN', $select->expr()->neq('ed.user', ':user'), 'THEN', '$nextToSign = :user' )
```

```
->andWhere( 'CASE', 'WHEN', $select->expr()->neq('ed.user', ':user'), 'THEN', $nextToSign = ':user' )
```

```
->andWhere( 'CASE', 'WHEN', $select->expr()->neq('ed.user', ':user'), 'THEN', $select->expr()->eq($nextToSign, ':user') )
```

```
->andWhere( "CASE", "WHEN", $select->expr()->neq("ed.user", ":user"), "THEN", $select->expr()->eq(":user", $nextToSign ), "END" )
```

and a few other variations

None of these work. Is there a way to make this kind of query with the query builder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have `END` to be added at the end of the statement.

Please refer [EBNF notation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#case-expressions) for case statement into Doctrine documentation for exact syntax specification.

So probably your code needs to look like this:

```
->andWhere('CASE WHEN ed.user != :user THEN <expr> END')
```

I'm not sure what does your `$select->expr()->eq($nextToSign, ':user')` statement actually means taking in mind that your code example shows that `$nextToSign` is query builder. Hence I've replaced this part of your statement with `<expr>`.

Comment: $nextToSign returns a user that should be the same as :user

Comment: @BrunoSouza then `<expr>` may be something like `:nextToSign = :user`